# Wordpress добавляет стили в header

Tags: wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем, как убрать собственно? использую стандартную тему "twentyseventeen"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это стили для верхней административной панели, они задаются в `\wp-includes/admin-bar.php`.

Чтобы выключить панель, снимите галку у "Показывать верхнюю панель при просмотре сайта" на странице [http://ваш_сайт/wp-admin/profile.php](http://%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%88_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/wp-admin/profile.php)